# Unit testing Apache Wink REST service with MockServletInvocationTest

Tags: junit, mocking, apache-wink

I use Apache Wink 1.2.1. I would like to unit test my REST service, and I'd rather doing it without using a [RestClient](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wink/wink-client/1.2.1-incubating/org/apache/wink/client/RestClient.java). I haven't found any example, but after a lot of searching around I guessed that [MockServletInvocationTest](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wink/wink-component-test-support/1.2.1-incubating/org/apache/wink/test/mock/SpringMockServletInvocationTest.java#SpringMockServletInvocationTest) was the right starting point ... however I have not been able to make it work.

Here is a minimal example that fails for me.

My REST service:

```
@Path("greetings")
public class GreetingsResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

The corresponding unit test:

```
public class GreetingsResourceTest extends MockServletInvocationTest {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { GreetingsResource.class };
    }


    public void testHello() throws ServletException, IOException {
        MockHttpServletRequest request = MockRequestConstructor.
            constructMockRequest("GET", "/greetings", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        MockHttpServletResponse response = invoke(request);
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
    }

}
```

So, I have a couple of questions:

1. Am I going in the wrong direction?
2. If I'm going in the right direction, then what am I doing wrong? When executing the previous test case I get the following error (which I really don't understand):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.getContentType()Ljava/lang/String;
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FlushResultHandler$FlushHeadersOutputStream.flushHeaders(FlushResultHandler.java:350)
>   ~[wink-server-1.2.1-incubating.jar:1.2.1-incubating]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what my problem was, and I just leave a note here in case someone had the same problem.

Here is why I got the `NoSuchMethodError`:

- I use [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to handle dependencies
- to use `MockHttpServletRequest` and `MockHttpServletResponse` I included a dependency to spring-mock 2.0.8:

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```
- unfortunately spring-mock 2.0.8 has a dependency to commons-logging 1.1, which, in turn, has a dependency to servlet-api 2.3, in which `javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.getContentType()Ljava/lang/String` does not exists! That method exists since servlet-api 2.4

So, to solve my problem I simply added an explicit dependency to servlet-api 2.4 with scope test! Now my unit test works without a problem!

Comment: how did you figure out the dependency error? `maven tree` ?

Comment: @bubuzzz: I honestly don't remember how I figured it out :) ... I guess because I was desperate, and I started going through all Maven dependency tree.