# Use Spring module without using Spring and Maven?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, apache-wink, apache-wink-spring

I'm currently working on a project that involves building a REST api using JavaEE. The setup of the project is Tomcat, Hibernate, Wink and Jackson Json for the different json-views. At the moment the unit testing of the rest resources is very poor, we've written custom classes that using introspection find the method that corresponds to a given resource but it is getting in our way (all the workarounds that we need to do in order to execute a simple unit test). I did a little research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203197/unit-testing-apache-wink-rest-service-with-mockservletinvocationtest).

My question is how to "install(add)" the MockServletInvocationTest class and its dependencies to the project? We're not using Maven, nor Spring. Is there a way to use Spring modules (I think this mock class is in the Spring test-module) outside Spring and if yes, how?

Comment: Spring is a collection of libraries. Pick one of them, packaged as a jar, and add it to your application classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, so for those who are interested: just add the following jars to your `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`:

- *spring-test-xx.jar*
- *spring-core-xx.jar*
- *wink-component-test-support-xx-incubating.jar*
- *commons-logging-xx.jar*

And everything workds fine.